# Derivative of quadratic form of complex valued matrices

Tags: derivatives, several-complex-variables

I want to take the derivative of $$\frac{\partial}{\partial W}(WS S^HW^H)$$ Where $W\in \mathbb C^{N\times M}$ and $S\in \mathbb C^{M\times M}$ symmetric matrix. My question, Is it straightforward derivative of quadratic form that should look like this $$2SS^HW$$

keeping in mind that all matrices are complex valued?

I appreciate your comments on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of the sesquilinear map

$$\Phi : (U,V) \mapsto USS^HV^H$$ is
$$d\Phi(U,V).(A,B) = A SS^H V^H + USS^HB^H.$$ Hence
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial W}(WS S^HW^H).A = A SS^H W^H + WSS^HA^H.$$ As $S$ is supposed to be hermitian, $A SS^H W^H = WSS^HA^H$ and therefore
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial W}(WS S^HW^H).A = 2 A SS^H W^H = 2WSS^HA^H$$